# graphically drawing UML diagrams in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, modeling

How can I draw graphically activity diagram in eclipse Mars?
I don't have a palette and design perspective. Is there anything that I should install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use eclipse modelling tools package from eclipse downloads

You can download it from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-modeling-tools/neonr)

Comment: Is it compatible with eclipse marse 1?

Comment: Yes it is compatible

Comment: Would you please give me the update site that I can install it on my eclipse mars?